# Add calculated column to count frequency of a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner. Here's an imaginary data set.
I want to identify unique values of 'Amount' within each 'Nutrient' and count them. My plan is to count how many times each 'Amount' appeared within each 'Nutrient' and then for those that is 1, it will be 'Y' for 'Unique', and 'N' if more than 1. I will then count how many unique values there are for each Nutrient. Finally, I want a new dataframe that shows the total count of 'Amount' and number of unique values for each 'Nutrient'.

Raw dataframe contains 'Food', 'Nutrient' and 'Amount', everything else is calculated.

```
Food | Nutrient | Amount | Count | Unique | Count_Unique

Apple | Fiber | 0.1 | 2 | N | 1

Apple | Sugar | 0.2 | 3 | N | 0

Apple | Fat | 0.3 | 2 | N | 1

Banana | Fiber | 0.2 | 1 | Y| 1

Banana | Sugar | 0.2 | 3 | N | 0

Banana | Fat | 0.1 | 1 | Y | 1

Corn | Fiber | 0.1 | 2 | N | 1

Corn | Sugar | 0.2 | 3 | N | 0

Corn | Fat | 0.3 | 2 | N | 1
```

Expected Output:

```
Nutrient | total count | number of unique values

Fiber | 3 | 1

Sugar | 3 | 0

Fat | 3 | 1
```

I know there is probably faster way to do this, but I would appreciate if you can teach me how to code my approach first so I can learn. Thank you very much.

Comment: _I would appreciate if you can teach me how to code my approach first so I can learn_ That seems entirely off-topic. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you the desired result.

```
df.groupby('Nutrient').agg(total_count=('Amount',lambda x:len(x)),unique = ('Unique',lambda x: len(x[x=='Y']))).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I got an error 'aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg' '. How can I solve it?

Comment: Are your columns named 'Nutrient', 'Amount' and 'Unique'?

Comment: I created an excel with the dummy data frame, but just the first three columns, so 'Food', 'Nutrient', 'Amount'. I thought 'Unique' will be added as a calculated column. Groupby.agg is new to me, so I'm still learning how your code works, but really appreciate your help! Thank you.

Comment: Without renaming the columns, I used:

Comment: Without renaming the columns, I used: 
Nutrient.groupby('Nutrient').agg({'Food':[lambda x : len(x)], 'Amount':[lambda x : len(x[x=='Y'])]}).reset_index()
but it's not returning what I want. Food returns 3 for each Nutrient, but Amount returned 0 for each Nutrient.

Comment: I dont think you need the square brackets before and after the lambda statements. For the amount perhaps you could do 'Amount': lambda x: len(df.loc[x.index,'Nutrient'][x=='Y'])

Comment: Thanks, I tried this: Nutrient.groupby('Nutrient').agg({'Food':'count', 'Amount': lambda x: len(Nutrient.loc[x.index,'Nutrient'][x=='Y'])}).rename({'Food': 'total count', 'Amount': 'number of unique values'}, axis=1), but the results were zero for 'number of unique values' for each Nutrient.